# Deploy feature on android without creating apk file

Tags: android, ios, react-native, deployment, release

For very small changes, it is sometimes very difficult to always deploy the features with a new **apk** files. Every time, the build number is increased for such a step and it *doesn't really looks good seeing so many apks*. So, I wanted to know, if there's a way, like we can deploy features on our android app and that could be done **without increasing any build number** or making new apk files. When tester confirms the scenarios then, we can go for pre-production/production release directly.

Answer (score 0):

There are severall approaches to this:

### Feature flags

By applying a programming pattern which allows you to enable / disable features in your app through configuration flags which can be toggled at runtime, it is possible to enable / dissable certain features in your app. Your app could check in your backend if a new configuration is available and enable features based on this configuration.

This makes shipping new features safer since they can easily be turned off if it turns out that they cause problems.

Firebase also offers a library for this called [Firebase Remote Config](https://firebase.google.com/docs/remote-config?hl=en).

### Use WebViews

For content that changes frequently, an easy solution is to implement the content as a website and use a WebView which loads the content from a web URL. The content can then easily be changed remotely.

An example that comes to mind is a "Latest promotions" page in a shopping app. Having the promotions page as a WebView gives designers full flexibility without requiring an app update.